# ListView Contextual Action Bar Support (>= Api 8)

Tags: android, android-listview, contextual-action-bar

I'm wondering maybe I've missed something..
Android has already provided support for `ActionMode` but on the developer page there's still this message

> Note: The contextual action mode is available on Android 3.0 (API level 11) and higher and is the preferred technique for displaying contextual actions when available. If your app supports versions lower than 3.0 then you should fall back to a floating context menu on those devices.

In my case I want to make ListView CAB for Android 2.2 upwards and searched on SO about the implementation of `ActionMode` support on a `ListView` and found nothing different than from android dev site. (and by nothing different I mean "you can't use this on android < 11" or "use actionbarsherlock")

**So.. do we have to implement both floating menu and CAB for multiple select `ListView` on Android 2.2 upwards? (because `setMultiChoiceModeListener (AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener listener)` is only available for api >= 11)**

Also I found that Google IO 2013 use this https://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/MultiSelectionUtil.java but hardly anyone ever mention this?

Comment: What are you using as your action bar backport? AppCompat? ActionBarSherlock? Something else? The answer may depend on what you are using.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm using ActionBarCompat, forgot to include, thank you